# Connecting MYSQL container with Python container through volume and pymysql

Tags: python, mysql, docker, pymysql

I need to connect a MYSQL container to a Python container so I can get the database from my MYSQL on this python container. I am using pymysql for this right now.

I made the containers with docker-compose I will link the documents down here. 
dockerfile.yml mysql the 'my-mysql' is mij custom mysql image

```
version: "3.3"

services:
  app-name: 
    build:
      context:  .
    image: my-mysql
    container_name: my-mysql
    ports:
     - '3308:3308'
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'root-password'
      MYSQL_DATABASE: 'bags'
      MYSQL_USER: 'user'
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: 'password'
    restart: unless-stopped
    expose: 
     - '3308'
volumes:
  data:
    external:
      name: data
```

Here is the `dockerfile.yml` for python the 'dataoverdracht' is my custom python image

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  app-name:
    build:
      context:  .
    image: dataoverdracht:1.0.0
    container_name: dataoverdracht
    ports:
     - 92:8080
    environment:
     - TARGET=$TARGET
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
     - .:/data
volumes:
  data:
    external:
      name: data
```

This is the python code I made for the container to connect with the mysql.

```py
import dash_html_components as html

import pymysql

import pandas as pd

connection = pymysql.connect("172.17.0.2","user","password","bags" )

cur = connection.cursor()

cur.execute("select * from filledbags LIMIT 10")

rows = cur.fetchall()

df = pd.DataFrame(rows)

print(df)
```

I have documents like the dockerfiles and the requirements.txt but I can promise you there is nothing wrong with them the only thing that can be handy is the expose from dockerfile python this is EXSPOSE 8080.

When I try to connect them I will get the error

```
pymysql.err.OperationalError: (1045, "Access denied for user 'user'@'172.18.0.2' (using password: YES)")
```

Can somebody explain to my what is wrong with my code. Btw: I did check different questions on this website I read some about changing my my.cnf I tried to look for my bind-address but it was not included in this file for me so this was no solution it seemed.

Comment: I would suggest go for https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/ have a look around. since you created 2 separate docker compose file. to begin with first check what is `url/port` of pymysql in your local machine, this will give you pretty much good start with what's wrong in your app's package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create the network for example `my_network`

`$ docker network create --driver=bridge my_network`

Then use it in docker-compose files.

`first_file.yml`

```
version: "3.3"

services:
  app-name:
    build:
      context: .
    image: my-mysql
    container_name: my-mysql
    ports:
      - "3308:3308"
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "root-password"
      MYSQL_DATABASE: "bags"
      MYSQL_USER: "user"
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: "password"
    restart: unless-stopped
    expose:
      - "3308"
    networks:
      - my_network

networks:
  my_network:
    external: true

volumes:
  data:
    external:
      name: data
```

`second_file.yml`

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  app-name:
    build:
      context: .
    image: dataoverdracht:1.0.0
    container_name: dataoverdracht
    ports:
      - 92:8080
    environment:
      - TARGET=$TARGET
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - .:/data
    networks:
      - my_network

networks:
  my_network:
    external: true

volumes:
  data:
    external:
      name: data
```

Then update your python code (use `my_network` instead of `172.17.0.2` ).

```
import dash_html_components as html

import pymysql

import pandas as pd

connection = pymysql.connect("my_network","user","password","bags" )

cur = connection.cursor()

cur.execute("select * from filledbags LIMIT 10")

rows = cur.fetchall()

df = pd.DataFrame(rows)

print(df)
```